# Vaadin: How to iterate over Tabs in a TabSheet?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

In Vaadin, say I have to find a Tab in a TabSheet based on its name.

How do I iterate over the Tabs in the Tabsheet to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can iterate the tabs and find them by the tab caption in the following way:

```
Iterator<Component> i = tabs.getComponentIterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Component c = (Component) i.next();
    Tab tab = tabs.getTab(c);
    if ("some_caption".equals(tab.getCaption())) {
         // found it
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `tabs` you have mentioned, of what type is it?


I used the following method, 
`TabSheet MyTabSheet= new TabSheet();
Iterator<Component> TabIterator = MyTabSheet.getComponentIterator();` and I run into heap space errors.

Comment: It is a tabsheet, like: TabSheet tabs = new Tabsheet(); Haven't encountered any heap problems with the code above.

Comment: The Reason I might be seeing Heap Problems is, Once I find that Tab, I have to add a new Tabsheet under that Tab.


Okay, this pops up:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1 cannot be cast to com.vaadin.ui.Component`

Comment: Ok, the problem might be modifying the TabSheet content while iterating it. You can avoid this by adding a placeholder (CssLayout for example) as tab content and adding the another components to that.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I kinda get the picture.
Still, I run into a ClassCastException when I try to TypeCast the Iterator to a component.
`Component MyComponent = (Component) MyTabIterator.next();`
This gets me a ClassCastException. Why so? Did it work for you?

Comment: No, above works like it should. Sounds weird that Iterator<Component> does not return Component. Actually, the cast is not even needed. As a sanity check: you are adding instances of Component to TabSheet?

Comment: After a few hours, I tailored the method you've specified to my ends, and it *works*. Now, I only add Tabs to the TabSheet, if there are doubts over whether Tabs are Components themselves or not, I am none the wiser. Anywas @eeq, problem solved thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#getComponentIterator()

Comment: Please let me know if my Implementation is Correct:


                                



`TabSheet MyTabSheet = new TabSheet();
    Iterator<Component> TabIterator = MainTabSheet.getComponentIterator()`;

And the subsequent code for iterating over the Tabs is:

`while(TabIterator.hasNext())`

Answer (score 3):

In Vaadin 7.x `getComponentIterator()` is deprecated. So @eeq answer is obsoleted.

In new manner his solution might look like:

```
Iterator<Component> iterator = tabSheet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Component component = iterator.next();
    TabSheet.Tab tab = tabSheet.getTab(component);
    if ("some tab caption".equals(tab.getCaption())) {
        // Found it!!!
    }
}
```

But since TabSheet implements `java.lang.Iterable<Component>` it could also look like this:

```
for (Component component : tabSheet) {
    TabSheet.Tab tab = tabSheet.getTab(component);
    if ("some tab caption".equals(tab.getCaption())) {
        // Found it!!!
    }
}
```

Or even in Java 8 style:

```
tabSheet.iterator().forEachRemaining(component -> {
    if ("some".equals(tabSheet.getTab(component).getCaption())) {
        // got it!!!
    }
});
```